# How create a personal branch with same name and content as origin

Tags: git

Lets say i have some code in my `origin` branch `abc`, which isn't merged to `master`. What i want to do, is to create a branch in my 'personal', with the same branch name `abc` and same content.

What is the best and easy way to do it?

Comment: git checkout -b abc origin/abc; git push personal abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local repo you can create a new branch with the same name, and then chek in it with:

```
git branch abc
git checkout abc
```

You can also do it quickly, create a branch and move inside it with a single command:

```
git checkout -b abc
```

If you want to track a `remote` branch with a local one you should do:

```
git branch abc remotes/abc --track
```

You can list the branches, locally and remotes with:

```
git branch -a
```

A more detailed view of all the branches and their `HEAD`:

```
git branch -va
```

Comment: About the last part.. So in my case it would be "git branch abc origin/abc --track", right..?

Comment: @ashipj Yes, if you want a local branch that tracks a remote one

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout abc`

If you don't have a branch named `abc` in your local repository, this command will create a local `abc` branch that will track an `origin/abc` branch. To be sure that your local repository knows about `origin/abc` branch, fetch it from origin: `git fetch origin`

Comment: i tried this, but the local branch is not tracking origin/abc..!

Comment: Maybe you have an outdated version of git. Check this out: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html A quote from it: `If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`